# Making legend with singleband pseudocolor in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer, legend, color-ramp

I have a continuous raster with values from around 0 to around 1. I used these parameters on the symbology tab:

[image]

When I head to the print layout and add a legend to my map, it displays like this (the photo only includes a portion of the legend):

[image]

Is it possible to transform that legend into something similar to the color ramp on the first photo? An horizontal and continuous legend from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 3):

Gradiant ramp based legends was introduced in QGIS 3.18, [see visual changelog](https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-gradient-ramp-based-legends) how to use.